# How can i put this into a list comprehension

Tags: python

write a function super_sum(A), that takes in an array of numbers A, and returns the sum of all the numbers after doubling the odd numbers and halving the even numbers.

heres my solution: how do solve this with a list comprehension

```
def super_sum(A):
    new_sum=[]
    total=0
    for x in A:
        if x%2==0:
            x=x/2
        elif x%2!=0:
            x=x*2
        new_sum.append(x)
    return sum(new_sum)

print (super_sum([10,3,5]))
```

Comment: List comprehension aside, no need for the `elif`, you can use `else`. This looks like homework?

Comment: It looks like the indentation is off in the question, could you take a look and correct that, @Wanjila?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @roganjosh, yes it was, and was wondering if there was a simplier way to do dit

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TankorSmash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum([x/2 if x%2==0 else x*2 for x in [10,3,5]])`